# Pandas: Split a specific column values to new columns and find occurrences of a value in all newly created columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have two columns called "family" and "severity". I would like to split the unique values in the "severity" column and find the occurrences of column "family" in newly created columns.

Initial Dataframe:

```
df

family severity
AA     High
BB     Critical
CC     Medium
DD     Low
AA     Low
CC     High
```

Output

```
df_output

family Critical High Medium Low Total
AA       0       1     0     1    2
BB       1       0     0     0    1
CC       0       1     1     0    2
DD       0       0     0     1    1
Total    1       2     1     2    6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) using `margins=True`:

```
final=pd.crosstab(df['family'],df['severity'],
       margins=True,margins_name='Total').rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print(final)
```

---

```
        Critical  High  Low  Medium  Total
family                                    
AA             0     1    1       0      2
BB             1     0    0       0      1
CC             0     1    0       1      2
DD             0     0    1       0      1
Total          1     2    2       1      6
```

From docs:

> margins : bool, default False
>   Add row/column margins (subtotals).
>
> margins_name : str, default ‘All’
>   Name of the row/column that will contain the totals when margins is True.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. What is the best way to interpret the final results from the above? I tried different plots but having "family" on Y-axis and "Total" on the y-axis will be helpful with some stacked plot representation. Please advise.

Comment: @Srini actually depends on your final goal. however I am not too experienced with visualization so I think it's best to ask a fresh plotting question :)